# Create Two Separate MongoDB instances on localhost

Tags: c#, mongodb, localhost

I am trying to find a way to have two separate locally hosted mongoDB instances so databases in one would not affect databases in the other. I have tried using different ports but this still leads to changes in one db affecting the other one but both need to be hosted locally. I saw on mongodb.org that I should change the config file but I am not sure where that is or how exactly to edit it (yes I know it will be some version of text or xml file.) If you have an example one you would be willing to post I would appreciate it. I am working on a windows machine using robomongo and I access the database with a c# 4.0 restful service

EDIT: I would also like to be able to have both connections open simultaneously.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to ensure that each instance has its own data directory, port and log file.

- [Set the data directory with `--dbpath`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-mongodb-processes/#specify-a-data-directory)
- [Set the port with `--port`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-mongodb-processes/#specify-a-tcp-port)
- [Set the log location with `--logpath`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-mongodb-processes/#start-mongod-as-a-daemon)

Make sure that all the directories you specify already exist before you launch the process. Mongod will throw an error and quit if it doesn't find the folder you specified in `--dbpath`, for example.

If you're on a linux machine, you can launch multiple mongod processes [from a single command session](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-mongodb-processes/#start-mongod-as-a-daemon) using `--fork`. Windows does this with the `start` command. Assuming `mongod.exe` is on your Path:

```
start mongod.exe --logpath C:\logs\log1.log --dbpath C:\data\db1 --port 27017
start mongod.exe --logpath C:\logs\log2.log --dbpath C:\data\db2 --port 27018
start mongod.exe --logpath C:\logs\log3.log --dbpath C:\data\db3 --port 27019
```

Each of these commands will spawn a new command window running a `mongod` process with the specified parameters. If you want to run MongoDB as a Windows Service, check out [the documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/#tutorial-mongod-as-windows-service)

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what it means to run mongodb as a windows service

Comment: It's a way to manage long-running programs. Per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d56de412.aspx): `Microsoft Windows services [...] enable you to create long-running executable applications that run in their own Windows sessions. These services can be automatically started when the computer boots, can be paused and restarted, and do not show any user interface. These features make services ideal for use on a server or whenever you need long-running functionality that does not interfere with other users who are working on the same computer.`

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need to change the config file (this is just for the mongod running on the default port as a service. You can simply start additional mongod instances with the config parameters from the command line (I don't use windows, but it should be quite similar to linux)

```
>  mongod --logpath "log/foo.log" --dbpath data/foo --port 27020 --fork
>  mongod --logpath "log/bar.log" --dbpath data/bar --port 27021 --fork
```

Comment: --fork isn't working for me. What does that extension do? This command (at least without --fork) didnt allow me to have two connections open. Sorry just added that

Comment: `--fork` is a linux specific command which detaches the process from the parent, it won't help on windows.

Comment: With these commands, my default port 27017 will be up? or this port will not work?